# Python-Oracle connection issue with Pyodbc

Tags: python, oracle, odbc, pyodbc

Tried to connect to the Oracle database using Pyodbc:

```
try:
    db_connection = pyodbc.connect('DSN=OraDev; PWD=%s' % Key.dbKeys['password'])
except pyodbc.Error, err:
        print >> debug_file, "Database connection failed: %s" %err 
        sys.exit()
```

and it keeps giving me this error message:

> '[IM014] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] The specified DSN
>   contains an architecture mismatch between the Driver and Application
>   (0) (SQLDriverConnect)

So I am wondering if the culprit is that I am not having the "matching" components. Currently, I have:

> 1. Python 2.7 32bit
> 2. Pyodbc 3.0.6 win32-py2.7
> 3. Oracle ODBC driver: 32bit
> 4. Windows server 2008 64bit
> 5. Oracle 11.2.0 64bit

Are there anything wrong with the versions here? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue you are having is that 64 bit Windows does not play well with 32 bit ODBC.  You can read more about it here:

[The 32-bit version of the ODBC Administrator tool and the 64-bit version of the ODBC Administrator tool display both the 32-bit user DSNs and the 64-bit user DSNs in a 64-bit version of the Windows operating system](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/942976).

The work around is to specifically target the ODBC driver for the architecture you are looking to implement.

A side note, trying to implement ODBC for oracle on a mixed architecture platform became a headache for us.  So, we implemented access to oracle through [CX_Oracle](http://cx-oracle.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: You need to find out whether your Oracle client is 32-bit or 64-bit.
Everything must be 64-bit or everything must be 32-bit you cannot
mix and match. Sometimes the 64-bit client also has
32-bit libraries but they will be in an alternative directory.