# Connecting to Oracle ODBC via Pyodbc (32-bit vs. 64-bit)

Tags: python, oracle, 32bit-64bit, pyodbc

I know similar questions have been asked before, and I still can't resolve my problem from looking at those Q's and their A's. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573741/python-oracle-connection-issue-with-pyodbc) is a similar problem.

My problem is this. At work, I have the following:

1. Windows machine (64 bit)
2. Python (64 bit)
3. Pyodbc module (64 bit)
4. Oracle ODBC driver (32 bit; only 32 bit can be used here)

When I execute the following line:

```
cnxn = pyodbc.connect(driver='{____}', dsn='____', uid='____', pwd='____')
```

I get the following error

```
Error: ('IM014', '[IM014] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] The specified DSN contains an architecture mismatch between the Driver and Application (0) (SQLDriverConnect)')
```

I have looked at `odbcad32.exe` file in both System32 and SysWOW64 folders. Both files contain the same information, as in both exe files show 32-bit Oracle driver.

What else can I do?

Comment: If the Oracle driver is limited to 32-bit, you'll need to use a 32-bit Python install. Should have no problems running that on 64-bit Windows.

Comment: As you suggested, on my 64-bit machine, I re-installed Python and Pyodbc, all now in 32-bit, to make them talk to each other. It's working! Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

As Bryan Eargle suggested above, keep 64-bit windows, but make the rest all 64-bit or 32-bit. I have Python, Pyodbc, and Oracle ODBC all in 32-bit, and they are now talking to each other.